# Want a timer start ticking on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I have a time counter in `jQuery/JS` start ticking once a client enters my website (on page load)?

I need some sort of function etc That can calculate the amount of time the visitor stays on my website (in seconds) to be used in an if statement.

Comment: Does the timer have to pause if the user leaves the page idle? What if they refresh the page? If it is okay that the timer resets to zero every time they navigate to a different page, then the answer is much simpler. If the timer should actually be a session timer, and it matters if they go idle, then the answer will be much more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply place the following script in the end of your document:

```js
// Counter
var enterDate = new Date();
function secondsSinceEnter()
{
  return (new Date() - enterDate) / 1000;
}

// Usage example
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  var sec = secondsSinceEnter();
  if (sec < 10)
      this.innerText = sec + " seconds";
  else
      this.innerText = 'You are here like for eternity';
};
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: How about if the visitors do not click on the button? Then OP cannot get the visiting duration!

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy The OP tells that he wants a function that **can calculate the amount of time the visitor stays on my website (sec) to be used in an if statement.**. `timeSinceEnter` function can be easily used in any `if` condition.

Comment: Please pay attention to what OP means, what if the user shuts down the page?

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy An answer should not be an absolute and exact answer to a question. Moreover, it is better when it is not. I have shown how to calculate how many time a user has spent on a page by now. Now, its OP's turn to choose how to use this timer for his needs. *"How can I have a time counter (in jQuery/JS) start ticking once a client enters my website (on page load)?"* is answered. Now the OP can try to make unload checking on his own, and he will come back when he meets any new problems.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy Btw, there is no need to be that agressive towards other answerers - it doesn't make you a better specialist, and doesn't make your answer more correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function(){
  setInterval(count, 1000);
};

let counter = 0;
function count(){
  counter++;
  //do stuff
}
```

The `count` Function is called all 1000ms=1s and increases the counter by one.

Comment: When the user is not focusing on the page, setInterval will temporarily stop.